# How to execute async code before redirect on vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, supabase

I'm building a app with [supabase](https://supabase.com/). I have a route that receives query parameters from a email magic link and I want to validate those parameters on supabase service before I redirect to a target url (also a query parameter). Example:

```js
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory("/"),
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/login",
      name: "login",
      beforeEnter: async (to) => {
        console.log("beforeEnter called");

        // Make request to supabase to validate parameters and login

        // Allow or deny
      },
      redirect: () => {
        console.log("redirect called");
        return { name: to.query.target };
      }
    },
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      component: Home,
      beforeEnter: () => {
        // Check supabase session
      }
    },
    // Other routes
  ]
});
```

Since I cant use `async` on the `redirect` function, I was hopping that I could use a `vue-router` guard, but `beforeEnter` and `beforeEach` are called after the redirect, therefore it does not works. Is there a way I can execute async code before redirecting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As confirmed in the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html),

> Note that Navigation Guards are not applied on the route that redirects, only on its target. e.g. In the above example, adding a beforeEnter guard to the /home route would not have any effect.

It's unnecessary to use `redirect`, this is solved with `beforeEnter` hook that provides everything to do conditional redirects:

```
  beforeEnter: async (to) => {
    ...
    if (...)
      return  { name: to.query.target };
    
    return false;
  },
```

Comment: Thanks. However it is strange that the `component` is required in Typescript since I'm always redirecting inside the `beforeEnter`.

Comment: That's not strange because it's presumed that the route may be navigated, beforeEnter could return true. View component is already resolved at this point. A dummy component can be provided.

Comment: The strangeness is not that the `component` is required when using `beforeEnter`, but that there is no way around it. I was able to use `component: () => null`, which I think it is best than using a existing component. Anyway, I added [this idea](https://github.com/vuejs/router/discussions/1713) in vue-router repo. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. It's typed in a way that makes sense for the majority of cases, https://unpkg.com/browse/vue-router@4.1.6/dist/vue-router.d.ts#L1013 , this one looks like edge case. Dummy component is `component: { render: () => null }`, will probably suit TS, or you can use type assertion